# Converting string data to hyperlink

Tags: c#, string, wpf, hyperlink

I would like to convert a string data which is in string array to hyperlink, which will be shown in messagebox.

The way I would like it to be (all in cs), doesn't work:

```
Button[] playBT = new Button[{amount of buttons}];
playBT[i] = KafelekPlay;
playBT[i].Click += KafelekPlay_Click;
Hyperlink linkPlay = new Hyperlink();
linkPlay.NavigateUri = albumy[nrAlbumu][tekscior][4]; //this is what i have problem with
void KafelekPlay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show(linkPlay);
}
```

Where "albumy[nrAlbumu][tekscior][4]" is the string data in string array i want to convert into hyperlink.